# JavaScript: get href value of multiple <a> tags

Tags: javascript, html

Without using jQuery or any other library, the objective is to inform the user which URL will visit with an alert event. In the markup, there are multiple `<a>` tags with different `href` values for each, when the user clicks the `<a>` tag, an `alert` event displays mentioning where the user is going before actually leaving the website.

**Workflow:**

1. The document loads
2. The user clicks an `<a>` tag
3. An `alert` event displays with the `href` value of the clicked `<a>` tag
4. Once the user closes the `alert` event, the browser starts loading the `href` website

**Code sample:**

```js
document.querySelector('a').onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = document.querySelector('a').href;
    alert('You are going to: ' + href);
    window.location = href;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a class="link" href="https://www.microsoft.com/">Link A</a>
  <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/">Link B</a>
  <a class="link" href="https://www.apple.com/">Link C</a>
</div>
```

**Objective:**

- Set up the JavaScript dynamically for all the `<a>` tags to achieve the workflow output for each one of them (and for any further `<a>` tags with the same `class` that might be included in the document). Please note that only **Link A** works as desired so far.

Your coding to solve this is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelector` will only match the *first* element that matches the selector. You can either use `querySelectorAll` to match all of those elements, add listeners to *all* of them...

OR

Attach *one* listener to the container ([event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) allows it to capture events from its children as they "bubble up" the DOM). When a child element is clicked the handler function checks that its an anchor with a `.link` class, and then executes the rest of the code.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
container.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.link')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { href } = e.target;
    alert(`You are going to: ${href}`);
    window.location = href;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a class="link" href="https://www.microsoft.com/">Link A</a>
  <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/">Link B</a>
  <a class="link" href="https://www.apple.com/">Link C</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelectorAll()` to get all the anchor tags, then loop through them and `addEventListener()` instead of `onclick`, because `onclick` can only be assigned to one element at a time. Also, you can grab the href with `e.target.href`. `e.target` is the element that was acted upon to start the event.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        if (e.target.matches('.link')) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var href = e.target.href;
          alert('You are going to: ' + href);
          //window.location = href;
       }
    })
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a class="link" href="https://www.microsoft.com/">Link A</a>
  <a class="link" href="https://www.google.com/">Link B</a>
  <a class="link" href="https://www.apple.com/">Link C</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Somehow ``e.target.href`` didn't worked. Alert event returns as "undefined". Tried on localhost :/

Comment: @ermac See my edit. I added an if statement from @Andy's answer, checking if the target has a `.link` class. This is due to the "bubbling up" effect he talks about.